# Как различить логические, сетевые диски и съемные носители?

Tags: java

Сейчас использую такое условие для определения дисков в системе:

```
public class MyOwnListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int idx, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {

    File file = (File) value;    
    if(file.getParent() == null){
            label.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(TestList.class.getResource("/icons/win_logicDisk_icon2.3.png")));
            setBackground(isSelected ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
        }
}
```

Но при таком условии все разновидности дисков(Логические, съемные диски, сетевые диски) имеют одну иконку и цвет выделения. Как разделить их по типам, для назначения каждому типу дисков своих оригинальных свойств(цвет выделения, иконка и т.д.)

Comment: `File file = (File) value` - прямо вершина парадигмы ООП :)

Comment: Win32_Volume.DriveType https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Akina проблема в том, что требуется кроссплатформенное решение и для Unix и для Windows и для много чего еще - это проклятие Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В vanilla Java эти данные недоступны, надо обращаться к средствам ОС.

Но, есть исключения - в состав Java Swing входит класс `FileSystemView`, который многие из нужных вам данных показывает.

Comment: вот взял я `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(file)` показывает он мне _Локальный диск_, но если винда будет Eng то уже не прочитает такое... может там уникальный номер типа можно получить, чтобы по нему ориентироваться?

Comment: сделал пока таким образом, не слишком гибко(ибо вдруг ОС будет на немецком), но по другому не знаю как... `FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
 String driveDescription = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(file).toLowerCase();
if (driveDescription.contains("локальный") || driveDescription.contains("local")) {` и т.д.